# INSERT query with SELECT query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[KitItem]
           ([KitItemGUID]
           ,[KitGroupID]
           ,[Name]
           ,[Description]
           ,[PriceDelta]
           ,[WeightDelta]
           ,[IsDefault]
           ,[DisplayOrder]
           ,[ExtensionData]
           ,[TextOptionMaxLength]
           ,[TextOptionWidth]
           ,[TextOptionHeight]
           ,[InventoryVariantID]
           ,[InventoryVariantColor]
           ,[InventoryVariantSize]
           ,[CreatedOn])
VALUES
...
...
...
```

I need to run another query to find out the KitGroupID based on the name which will be a font.

Here is how i roughly want to do it:

```
SELECT TOP1 (KitGroupID)
FROM KitGroup
WHERE Name = "Font"
AND ProductID = 157
```

I have about 30 productIDs and i have many fonts.

I need to run the insert statement then while its running i need the select query to find out the KitGroupID to then finalise the insert. Does that make sense?

How can i do this, i am quite new to SQL.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry bu for me it does not make sense, you are going to INSERT into KITGROUP and SELECT from KITGROUP in the same time?

Comment: He's inserting into KITITEM, not KITGROUP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `INSERT` from a `SELECT` statement, and include a lot of literals in that `SELECT`:

```
INSERT [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[KitItem]
     -- all your column names
SELECT TOP 1
    'Value',
    23,
    [KitGroupId],
    'More values',
    -- ...
FROM [KitGroup] WHERE ...
```

Comment: what do you call this sort of query, i would like to read up on it?

Comment: It's an [INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335(v=SQL.100).aspx) query, using a derived table.

Comment: please look at my example, i still dont see how the select statement will add the values to the insert?

Comment: @PD24 There are two ways to `INSERT` data - you can use `VALUES`, or you can use `SELECT`. In your original example, if you change `VALUES ( 'value1', 'value2', etc )` for `SELECT 'value1', 'value2', etc` you'll see that the both insert the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like so:

```
INSERT INTO [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[KitItem]
           ([KitItemGUID]
           ,[KitGroupID]
           ,[Name]
           ,[Description]
           ,[PriceDelta]
           ,[WeightDelta]
           ,[IsDefault]
           ,[DisplayOrder]
           ,[ExtensionData]
           ,[TextOptionMaxLength]
           ,[TextOptionWidth]
           ,[TextOptionHeight]
           ,[InventoryVariantID]
           ,[InventoryVariantColor]
           ,[InventoryVariantSize]
           ,[CreatedOn])
SELECT 
  NEWID(),
  (
    SELECT TOP1 (KitGroupID)
    FROM KitGroup
    WHERE Name = "Font"
    AND ProductID = 157
  )
  , anotherConstantValue ...
```

Comment: anotherConstantValue ... ? what does this mean?

Comment: The same as your '...' or Kirk's 'More values'. Kirks answer is a bit more elegant than mine, PROVIDED that there is always a KitGroup value for the ProductId and Name. If there isnt' a record, then my answer will attempt a NULL insert into KitValue.KitGroupId whereas Kirk's query won't insert a record at all in this instance.

Comment: what do you call this sort of query?

Comment: INSERT..VALUES isn't the onlt form of insert - you can also INSERT ... SELECT (insert multiple rows, usually from other tables) and INSERT ... EXEC (i.e. insert the output of a PROC). See MSDN examples here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sql:

```
INSERT INSERT INTO [StoreTestDB].[dbo].[KitItem]([KitGroupID],[Name],[PriceDelta],[WeightDelta],[IsDefault],[DisplayOrder],[InventoryVariantID]) VALUES (17,'<ml><locale name="en-GB">Gaudi</locale></ml>',0,0,1,1,0)       
SELECT TOP (1) KitGroupID, Name, ProductID FROM KitGroup WHERE (Name = 'Fonts') AND (ProductID = 157)
```

Comment: Just curious: In what way does your SELECT finalises your INSERT?